# Received order from a "blocked" country

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, shipping-address, billing-address

since the magentocommerce board isn't available for new topics I give it a try on StackExchange.

Today we received an order from a "blocked" country (not allowed via country options). Our customer entered a valid, allowed shipping address but an address from a "not allowed" country for the billing-address. My questions is: can we fully deny (shipping- and billing-address) orders from "not allowed" countries or is there something just misconfigured?
The main problem with such a behaviour is, that we just have a tax-table for allowed countries, disallowed countries will get an incorrect, tax-free, bill.

We're using Magento CE 1.8.1.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves, the billing address is restricted based on the `System > Configuration > General > Allowed Countries` options.

Comment: Country is not marked in System > Configuration > General > Allowed Countries options, so either there has to be another option or something else on the magento installation is wrong. I'll try a fresh demo installation and check if this behaviour persists tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

We recently had to change our allowed countries to restrict shipping to only one country. Now we received an order from a registered customer that had registered with a country that is now no longer supported, however the order went through. Can anbody confirm this issue?